# PHP average rating system

Tags: php, system, rating, rank

I am building a website where people can rate other user profile's on a scale of 1-5.

My question is:

How do i make it so that every rating a user receives the average is calculated. Then depending on a users average rating they are given a rank number. The user with the highest average rating is ranked number 1 and so on and so on.

Comment: where are you storing this data, do you have a database?  It would be best to let the DB average and sort the data as you retrieve it.

Comment: I do not know too much PHP but yes i am using a database MySQL

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg

Comment: I am really inexperienced with PHP so it would be good if you could give me some straight forward, black and white answers.

Comment: yeah as Surabhil suggested you'll want to use the avg() command in your mysql select and either sort there, or via one of the php sort methods

Comment: what does your database look like? How are you storing data?

Comment: Do you have some code that you can't get to work?

Answer (score 0):

With a table `users_ratings` with columns `user_id` and `rating`

Insert a new rating.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users_ratings SET user_id=$user_id, rating=$rating"
```

Retrieve users and average rating ordered by average rating (highest first).

```
$sql = "SELECT user_id, avg_rating AS AVG(rating) FROM users_ratings GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY AVG(rating) DESC"
```

Comment: Might be able to just do: `ORDER BY avg_rating DESC` - I'm not sure but `AVG(rating)` should definitely work.